# Looking for generic PHP error_handler

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to override the default PHP error handler.I'm sure this has been implemented countless times.

I've found the following projects, but most seem quite old and small projects.

I would primarily like to have:

- Development mode, that simply displays all errors/notifications
- Production mode, that allows displaying clean custom lay-out pages to the user
- Logging to text file (i don't have admin access to the webserver, so can't set this up through the PHP settings)
- Send warning e-mails on serious errors
- Log to database

How can this be done in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function to set your custom error handler and then do whatever you'd like with it.

The best practice, IMO, is to throw [`ErrorException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) when error occurs and handle it with `try/catch` (**Note:** with handling I don't mean muting errors). For example:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
    //Some code that may produce error
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    $someLogger->log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Instead of logger you may have your own custom class that will implement your requirements. So if any of already existing source meets your needs use one, otherwise create.

**Note #1:** If you want to do something on *fatal errors* (logging comes in my mind) you can use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

**Note #2:** You said that classes/projects you've found are small. There are two things. First, you can't measure how good code is with LOC. Second, there;s not really much to do with errors.

**Edit:**

In general, it's not common and not even acceptable to re-implement everything from the ground when you develop new project. You should build your own libraries once and then use them in your projects. Personally, I use [KLogger](https://github.com/katzgrau/KLogger) for logging stuff and I am happy with it.

Comment: I guess that throw ErrorException is OK only when you are in developing... NOT in production, when a E_NOTICE can break the flow of the program

Comment: @Laxus `set_error_handler ( callable $error_handler [, int $error_types = E_ALL | E_STRICT ] )` as you see, second parameter is for filtering error types. So you can control on which errors you should throw `ErrorException`. And `ErrorException` is good at every environment. It's up to you how you will treat it.

Comment: @Laxus Also you can return `false` from the error handler function to prevent a break in the normal flow, which is useful when you want to handle some `E_NOTICE`/`E_WARNING`s with an exception but not others.

Comment: This is all useful information on how to handle errors, but i'm not looking into re-inventing the wheel. Or is it common for most web developers to re-implement this each time they build a website? Even if it's just a small set of features, it's the same thing all over again each time, no?

Comment: @PLB: Good point about the LOC, i should look into what they actually support, but before digging through the code of 5 projects, i thought maybe i could find a consensus in the webdev community on what public project to use.

Comment: @Wouter No, it's not common and not even acceptable to re-implement everything from the ground when you develop new project. You should build your own libraries _once_ and then use them in your projects. Personally, I use [KLogger](https://github.com/katzgrau/KLogger) for logging stuff and I am happy with it.

Comment: @PLB: thanks, that's what i was looking for. You can post it as an answer so i can upvote it.